# Knot theory question

Tags: knot-theory

Show that a (p,q) torus knot always has a projection with  p(q-1) crossings.

I can show an example using (2,3) has 4 crossings. I think there is something more to this. Help please

Comment: what, exactly, are you quoting?

Comment: The question is from the knot book by Colin Adams question 5.4 if that's what your asking

Answer (score 2):

So, this is pretty self explanatory from the picture, but we have $q$ strands and $p$ times that the outside strand wraps over the other $q-1$. Hence, $p(q-1)$ crossings.

[image: A p q torus knot with standard projection]